# Does the PHP fopen() "a" mode need file locking?

Tags: php, fopen

I vaguely remember years ago someone saying that the a mode in the PHP fopen() call doesn't file locking - is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) does not mention anything about locking.

However, there are some references about the [`flock` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php). This function is to be called after `fopen` as it takes a stream handle as parameter.

It allows to acquire an exclusive lock, or a shared lock. It can also be released manually or automatically when calling `fclose` on locked resource, or when the said resource is garbage collected.